# Question about adding nodes to jedisCluster

Tags: java, kotlin, jedis, redis-cluster

I have been reading what seems to be conflicting information to me on the correct way to setup jedisCluster. According to what I read on the Jedis GitHub, they state that you only need one of the nodes and jedisCluster will discover the others. I have read others stating that you should add all masters, and yet others say to add all nodes. So, which is the best way to configure this?  Any information on the best way to go with this is greatly appreciated.

Also, can you still us the single Redis stack Docker container with jedisCluster? I plan to just use the Redis Cluster that will be in our Kubernetes when in the office, but we need a way to work on this when out of the office. I'm supposed to get all this figured out in 1 sprint along with a few changes, and we have lost most of our senior developers. Joy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my main question in the article I linked below in case anyone else comes looking for more information.

With jedisCluster you only need to add some of the nodes, from there it will retrieve the information for the other nodes since they all share this information. So, in my case I plan to just add the 3 master nodes. I will update if the standalone stack works or not once, I make it that far in my setup.

[https://www.programmerall.com/article/8540798580/#:~:text=Since%20each%20node%20contains%20all%20node%20information%2C%20the,configurations%20are%20for%20high%20availability%29.%20127.0.0.1%3A9380%3E%20cluster%20nodes](https://www.programmerall.com/article/8540798580/#:%7E:text=Since%20each%20node%20contains%20all%20node%20information%2C%20the,configurations%20are%20for%20high%20availability%29.%20127.0.0.1%3A9380%3E%20cluster%20nodes)